# My Axios api call does not retrieve data fast enough

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using the Axios library to retrieve data from an API.

Most of the times it works, but when it retrieves a larger slice of data, it seems to not load it fast enough, and the api response is just empty. There are no timeouts or anything, I just get no data back.

But I know there is data in there because sometimes it does work for the same call and id, and sometimes it doesn't...but there are never any errors in the console...just an empty return.

I was wondering if there was something I could do.  Like maybe add a wait period?  Or is there a way to make it go faster?

Thanks!

Here is my render with the function below:

```
render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    this.getLockNumber(id);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.lockLocation}</h1>
        </div>
}

async getLockNumber(id) {
    try {
        const { data: response } = await axios.get(`/api/building/lock/${id}`) 
        this.setState({ lockLocation: response[0].locationName });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? Did you see your server responded correctly under network tab?

Comment: @ducmai no errors and the response was 200 OK

Comment: and the response under network tab looks correctly I guess?

Comment: @ducmai the response is a 200 Ok, but there is no data most of the time.